# How to use StartActivityForResult for fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently I am using fragments in my project. But for search screen alone I am using separate Activity. I am try to convert that activity to fragment. My problem is currently I I am call the search activity from fragment like

```
private void callLocationSearch() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SearchDataFilterActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVE_INTENT_DATA, activity.getResources().getString(R.string.location));
        startActivityForResult(intent, FOR_SEARCH_LOCATION);
    }
```

From Search screen  I set result and send to the previous screen.

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

So that in `onActivityResult` I get the the result and set in the search field. I have multiple fields in this screen. So I search from the search activity and set in this fragment. Now I changed Search activity to Fragment. The problem is I am not able to do setResult and send back to fragment. I can only to create another fragment and pass the values. So that the previous values are getting loss. Please let me any idea to solve my issue.

Herewith I attached the screenshots:

First one is fragment
[image: Fragment Image]

Second one is Search Activity. 
[image: Activity]

For More clarification I attached one more image.
[image]

Comment: May you post the screen? I can't still imagine how it looked

Comment: Added screenshot. Please review.

Answer (score 1):

You should use listeners, in Fragment B you do

```
private OnSomethingSelectedListener mListener;

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnSomethingSelectedListener {
    public void onSearchComplete(Result object or more params);
}
```

Fragment A (or the class that should receive the information) should implement FragmentB.OnSomethingSelectedListener and the onSearchComplete method.
In Fragment A or in Activity (when you create Fragment B) you can pass the instance (Fragment A or Activity) to the Fragment B constructor like

```
FragmentB b = new FragmentB(this);

public FragmentB(OnSomethingSelectedListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

now...in Fragment B instead of using setResult you will use

```
mListener.onSearchComplete(result);
```

This is a simple listener, which is the way to go for fragments communications, you can read more about this here

[Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: This is the best practice, but missing a thing. I think its better to find fragment B by tag rather than construct new fragment since fragment is added or replaced by fragment manager. Cmiiw

Answer (score 0):

In fragment you have use "getActivity()"

```
 getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

Comment: This is for Intent. But I am asking about fragment to fragment.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways popped up on my mind:
1. Use localbroadcast to send the value from fragment B to fragment A
2. Store the value on SharedPreferences after search done and get it on fragment in onResume.

Choose your way :)